# F# Continuation Passing Style (int -> int -> int) option

Tags: f#, expressionbuilder, cps

I am making a function that takes one function, 2 integer values as input.
I have to check whether the function and the values are None or Some. Some, None and option is quite confusing.
The concept is simple but I don't get how to apply it into F# codes.

In the problem, the input will be

First problem

```
  let f = Some (fun x y -> x + y)

  let fst = Some 42

  let snd = Some 42

expectation = Some 84
```

Second problem

```
  let f = Some (fun x y -> x + y)

  let fst = None

  let snd = Some 42

expectation = None
```

I also have to use

```
type MaybeBuilder () =

  member __.Bind (m, f) = Option.bind f m

  member __.Return (m) = Some m

let maybe = MaybeBuilder ()
```

this builder.

I tried let! and many other crazy things but failed.
Some (fun x y -> x+y) is (int -> int -> int) option and I don't know how to manipulate this function.
It keeps saying that this is not a function and it cannot be applied.

Comment: Can you please post your failed attempts and explain what want wrong with them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
let expectation =
    maybe {
        let! func = f
        let! a = fst
        let! b = snd
        return func a b
    }
```

Because your function is inside a Maybe, you cannot use it directly. Using `let!` allows you reach inside the maybe.

Comment: This was the correct answer. Thank you
I did not write "let! func = f"